# Adding two images in one .Json Object

Tags: arrays, json, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic3

I'm building a Mobile App using Ionic 3 and I'm trying to display a few images in one ion-card using an array.

HTML:

```
<ion-card>
    <img [src]="productDetails.images"/>
    <ion-card-header>
      Description
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      {{productDetails.description}}
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Oreo",
    "description": "Our pre-shrunk organic cotton t-shirt, with its slightly fitted waist and elegant V-neck is designed to flatter. Youll want one in every color!",
    "price": "520.00",
    "image": "https://podcollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Love-is-a-Cosmic-Force-Alex-Grey.jpg",
    "images": [
      "https://podcollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Love-is-a-Cosmic-Force-Alex-Grey.jpg", 
      "https://podcollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Love-is-a-Cosmic-Force-Alex-Grey.jpg"
    ],
    "bestSeller": true,
  }
]
```

I can successfully display only one image when using "productDetails.image" but not when I try with "productDetails.images".

I get this:

[Mobile Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu5Tz.png)

My questions is, is it possible to display both images? Or the only option is to create more objects values and display them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well that because productDetails.images is an array and as a result when you use it you are not returning the link to an image but are linking the array itself so if you wore to use productDetails.images[0] then you would have the first image etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display all the images from the productDetails, then you need to use below modified HTML code:

```
<ion-card>
  <div *ngFor="let productImage of productDetails[0].images let i = index" >
     <img [src]="productImage" />
  </div>
  <ion-card-header>
     Description
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
     {{productDetails.description}}
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```